# Is there any way to retrieve a appended int value to a String in javaScript?

Tags: string

I am currently working on a project that dynamically displays DB content into table. 
To edit the table contents i am want to use the dynamically created "string"+id value.

Is there any way to retrieve the appended int value from the whole string in javaScript?

Any suggestions would be appreciative...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the string part is only going to consist of letters or non-numeric characters, you could use a regular expression:

```
var str = "something123"
var id = str.replace(/^[^\d]+/i, "");
```

If it can consist of numbers as well, then things get complicated unless you can ensure that `string` always ends with a non-numeric character. In which case, you can do something like this:

```
var str = "something123"
var id = str.match(/\d+$/) ? str.match(/\d+$/)[0] : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(''+string.match(/\d+/) || '')
```

Explanation: match all digits in the variable `string`, and make a string from it (`''+`).
If there is no match, it would return null, but thanks to `|| ''`, it will always be a string.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the regex:

```
/\d+$/
```

to retrieve the appended number